# Subset a dataframe in R based on another dataframe, taking multiple hits

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, subset

I have two dataframes

df1

```
names   target   start  end

Gene_1  chr5     1      345
Gene_2  chr1     1      678
Gene_3  chr4     1      909
Gene_4  chr48    1      876
Gene_5  chr8     1      432
Gene_6  chr9     1      556
Gene_7  chr12    1      345
```

df2

```
gene_names   positions

Gene_1       221
Gene_2       34
Gene_2       444
Gene_2       324
Gene_3       99
Gene_3       232
Gene_4       221
Gene_4       334
Gene_4       390
Gene_6       200
Gene_7       146
```

`df1` is way shorter than `df2`.
The first column of `df2` has repeated observations with different values in the second column. Its first column lacks some match (a lot) of the observations in the homologous column in `df1`.

I wanted to merge them into a `df_new`, which contains the `gene_names` and the other column from `df2` together with the related information from the other column of `df1`, even repeated when the observation in `gene_names` appears 2+ times.

I paved my way with merge

```
df_new<-merge(df2, df1, by.x = "gene_names", by.y = "names")
```

and I have a tentatively result of which I am mostly unsure.
Someone can shed more light?

Intended output

df_new

```
gene_names   positions  target   start  end

Gene_1       221        chr5     1      345
Gene_2       34         chr1     1      678
Gene_2       444        chr1     1      678
Gene_2       324        chr1     1      678
Gene_3       99         chr4     1      909
Gene_3       232        chr4     1      909
Gene_4       221        chr48    1      876
Gene_4       334        chr48    1      876
Gene_4       390        chr48    1      876
Gene_6       200        chr9     1      556
Gene_7       146        chr12    1      345
```

Comment: Based on the data shared `df_new<-merge(df2, df1, by.x = "gene_names", by.y = "names")` gives the expected output it seems. What is not working in your original data?

Comment: I expected it to contain a slightly higher number of observations. Maybe I should cross-check the quality of the data I'm merging...

Comment: ``` df_new<-merge(df1, df2,  by.x = "names", by.y = ""gene_names"")``` 
 returns the same, sems to me, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `right_join` with `df1` and `df2`:

```
library(dplyr)
df_result <- df2 %>% 
  right_join(df1, by= c("gene_names"="names"))
```

output:

```
   gene_names positions target start   end
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Gene_1           221 chr5       1   345
 2 Gene_2            34 chr1       1   678
 3 Gene_2           444 chr1       1   678
 4 Gene_2           324 chr1       1   678
 5 Gene_3            99 chr4       1   909
 6 Gene_3           232 chr4       1   909
 7 Gene_4           221 chr48      1   876
 8 Gene_4           334 chr48      1   876
 9 Gene_4           390 chr48      1   876
10 Gene_6           200 chr9       1   556
11 Gene_7           146 chr12      1   345
12 Gene_5            NA chr8       1   432
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(names = c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_4", 
"Gene_5", "Gene_6", "Gene_7"), target = c("chr5", "chr1", "chr4", 
"chr48", "chr8", "chr9", "chr12"), start = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), end = c(345, 678, 909, 876, 432, 556, 345)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))

df2 <- structure(list(gene_names = c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", "Gene_2", "Gene_2", 
"Gene_3", "Gene_3", "Gene_4", "Gene_4", "Gene_4", "Gene_6", "Gene_7"
), positions = c(221, 34, 444, 324, 99, 232, 221, 334, 390, 200, 
146)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(df1, df2, all.y = TRUE, by.x = "gene_names", by.y = "names")
```